# Heroku rake assets:precompile too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-sync

When I do `heroku rake assets:precompile` this takes almost 15 minutes everytime I do this and it's taking too long.

I am using asset_sync with heroku with S3 but is there a way to speed up this process?

Comment: what about running rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production ? works for me when running my app on heroku, just ensure your heroku app has all your S3 credentials?

Comment: Did you find an acceptable solution for this? I'm running into this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can precompile assets locally, which will usually be faster.  If you are doing this, make sure you have a [pre-commit compile git hook](http://githooks.com/) so that you don't forget to precompile on deploy (make sure to use `RAILS_ENV=production` !)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compiling-assets-locally

> If a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will
>   assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not
>   attempt to compile your assets. Rails 4 uses a file called
>   public/assets/manifest-.json instead. More recent versuions
>   use public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-.json (note the dot .
>   indicating it may be hidden by default on your machine). On all
>   versions you can generate this file by running $ rake
>   assets:precompile locally and checking the resultant files into Git.